# Chaining queries in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, flask, mongoengine

I'm implementing a REST API for a standard CRUD app. In one example, to get a list of users, clients can call:

`GET api.site.com/users`  *(and optionally)* `?name=x`  `phone=x`  `email=x`

Passing the above optional parameters filters the users I search for.

I'm trying to implement this logic in Python. I'm thinking of chaining sub-queries, like so:

Given:

`users = User.objects()`

Then:

```
if 'name' in request.args:
    users = users.objects(name = request.args['name'])
```

And:

```
# List of users is smaller after filtering by name
if 'phone' in request.args:
    users = users.objects(phone = request.args['phone'])
```

And:

```
# List of users is smaller after filtering by phone
if 'email' in request.args:
    users = users.objects(email = request.args['email'])
```

But the method isn't available, and I can't find out how to do this by checking the MongoEngine API reference or User Guide or tutorial.

**What can I do to chain sub-queries in MongoEngine?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since, [mongoengine supports keyword arguments to the `objects` call](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/queryset/base.py#L92), you can create a dictionary, with the *keys* as field_names, and *values* as field_values. And then use this dictionary while querying. For example:

```
query = {}

if 'name' in request.args:
    query['name'] = request.args['name']

if 'phone' in request.args:
    query['phone'] = request.args['phone']

if 'email' in request.args:
    query['email'] = request.args['email']

user = User.objects(**query)
```

The above is just a sample, you might want to add security measures, and maybe have a default query, depending on your app.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.__call__
The mongoengine.QuerySet object itself is callable. Chaining queries can be done simply by calling the result queryset.

```
users = User.objects()

if 'name' in request.args:
    users = users(name = request.args['name'])

if 'phone' in request.args:
    users = users(phone = request.args['phone'])

if 'email' in request.args:
    users = users(email = request.args['email'])
```